# Multiple SUMIFS in Excel not working as expected

Tags: excel, ms-office, sumifs

I'm trying to tally up results from another sheet in excel if they match specific criteria. I have successfully looked up and implemented the `SUMIF` function like so:

```
=SUMIF('General Expenses'!C:C,"*Office Supplies*",'General Expenses'!D:D)
```

This returns the expected output. Now I'm trying to use the function `SUMIFS` to filter using multiple criteria (year & category) ex:

```
=SUMIFS('General Expenses'!D:D,'General Expenses'!A:A,"*2012*",'General Expenses'!C:C,"Office Supplies")
```

This does not work as expected and gives me `0` as the value. Below is what the `General Expenses` sheet looks like:

```
DATE        PLACE          CATEGORY           AMOUNT
1/1/2012    Staples        Office Supplies    $ 18.40
1/3/2012    Staples        Office Supplies    $  5.63
1/5/2012    Staples        Office Supplies    $ 54.00
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I don't see the year in your formula.

Comment: It shows 0 when the value should be higher

Comment: Just to clearify why you "don't see the year in pnuts formula" In excel all dates are stores as a number, the number that represents the number of days a date is from 1/1/1900, so in pnuts formula the `>40908 ` is the same as `>12/31/2011` and the `<41275` is the same as `<1/1/2013` the same thing as saying the `year=2012`.

Comment: @pnuts huh? times are represented as decimals. they are fractions of a day. you did not include a decimal. But how would a time add a year any how?

Comment: @pnuts gotcha, exactly why I normally use inclusive ranges, `">=40909"`  but good clarification.

Comment: @user2140261 if I had dates in there that are greater/less than 2012 (2013/2011) they would be calculated in that as well then no? @ pnuts it works (kind of)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((RIGHT(TEXT('General Expenses'!A:A,"dd/mm/yyyy"),4)="2012")*('General Expenses'!C:C="Office Supplies"),('General Expenses'!D:D))
```

Comment: I've update my answer - change last `*` to `,` (you have some non numeric values in column `D`)

Comment: still doing the same thing